# want to mount box storage on ubuntu

Tags: mount, fstab

I want to mount box storage on Ubuntu 22.04.
https://geekrewind.com/how-to-mount-box-on-ubuntu/ 
I'm trying to mount Box by looking at web pages like these, but it doesn't work. 
The TLS connection was non-properly terminated and cannot be added to other locations. Also, in `/etc/fstab`,I added `https://dav.box.com/dav /home/MyName/Box davfs rw,user,noauto 0 0`, but it says can't find in `/etc/fstab`. Now, I can't mount it. 
Please tell me how to mount the box.

[image]

Comment: Did you install `davfs2` successfully? Did you make the change to the config file? Did you create the folder Box? Did you add yourself to the group? If yes to all, copy and paste the error you get when you use the `mount Box` in your question. Note, in Ubuntu Box and box are two different folders.

Comment: I tried again exactly and the error changed.
`/sbin/mount.davfs: Mounting failed.
SSL handshake failed: Connection reset by peer`
  Please refer to the error image attached above for details.